# Enforcing valid filenames within Rails application codebase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I enforce that filenames within a Rails application are valid? For example, not allowing a filename of `app/models/.rb`, or something with `config/my_configuration.yml` (with a space after "yml")?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to prevent these files from appearing in your revision control system.

For example, if you use git, take a look at git hooks (and especially at git pre-commit hooks, since you want the verification that the filename is correct to be made before validating the commit). I think you can write validations based on regular expressions that will abort the commit if the validations fail.

You can write hooks in Ruby, for example check [here](https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy).